# How to convert BigQuery Timestamp to DateTime?

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm using Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2 to access big query. In my table I have a field created_at which is in Timestamp(ex: 2019-08-11 11:22:22.123 UTC). When I tried to convert this field into C# datetime it gives the following output:

```
8/11/2019 11:22:22 PM
```

And when I tried to convert this into a datetime (format : yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff) it gives me the following value

```
2019-08-11 22:22:22.0000000
```

But I want my output to look like this `2019-08-11 11:22:22.1230000`

Here is my code

```
string created_at = $"{row["created_at"]}".ToString() == null ? "" : $"{row["created_at"]}".ToString();

DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(created_at, "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string newDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff");

Console.WriteLine (newDate);
```

What am I doing wrong here? How to get milliseconds?

Comment: DateTime has no format, it's a binary value. Formats apply only when creating a string for display. What are the *actual* contents of `row["created_at"]`? It may already a `DateTime` that doesn't need any other conversion.

Comment: `$"{row["created_at"]}".ToString()` will never be null because even if `row["created_at"]` is null the interpolated string will format the null value as an empty string.  Also calling `ToString` on a `string` is pointless.

Comment: BTW `$"{row["created_at"]}".ToString() == null `is pointless and always false. `$"{row["created_at"]}` already created a string. It that column contained a string, that operation did nothing except return the string. If it was a DateTime it created a string using your account's locale. Calling `ToString()` on it will do nothing. Comparing that string to `null`will always be false

Comment: Store `row["created_at"]` somewhere and check it, eg `var created=row["created_at"];`. What is its type? Is it a string? A `DateTime`? What does `created.GetType()` return?

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact(created_at, "M/d/yyyy H:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` doesn't parse ms, so when you display the value with ms (`.fffffff`) it's not going to show anything

Comment: What happens if you try `DateTime? date=(DateTime?)row["created_at"];`? If that works, it means you already have a DateTime. The strings posted in this question wouldn't appear unless either `BigQuery` returned a DateTime or a US date string instead of `2019-08-11 11:22:22.123 UTC`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos actual content of row["created_at"] are in timestamp

Comment: @MuhammadHammadEjaz there's no such data type. What are the actual contents? What is the value's type? Is it a `string`? A `DateTime`? Something else? I'd bet that BiqQuery's client returns proper .NET types, not just strings

Comment: @MuhammadHammadEjaz are you *sure* you want a 12-hour value *without* an AM/PM designator? If you use `hh` you'll have to include `tt` at the end otherwise people won't be able to tell whether it's 11 AM or 11 PM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
var date=(DateTime?)row["created_at"];
var text=string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt}", date, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
var date=(DateTime?)row["created_at"];
var text=FormattableString.Invariant($"{date:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt}");
```

To read a `BigQueryDbType.Timestamp` value and format it into a string using a 12-hour notation and AM/PM designator in English.

**Explanation**

The [source code itself](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/BigQueryRow.cs#L89) shows that calling `row["created_at"]` converts a [BigQueryDbType.Timestamp](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/BigQueryRow.cs#L153) type gets converted [to a UTC DateTime](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/master/apis/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/BigQueryRow.cs#L66). This means that this code will work :

```
var date=(DateTime?)row["created_at"];
```

The returned date contains all the information there is. If the value contains milliseconds, `date` will also contain milliseconds. The source code shows that the value's precision is 10 microseconds.

DateTime is a binary value, it has no format. Formats apply only when a string needs to be parsed into a DateTime value or when a DateTime value needs to be formatted as a string for display or saving to a text file, with `ToString()`, `String.Format()` or string interpolation.

For example, the `o` [standard format specifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#the-round-trip-o-o-format-specifier) creates a string in the ISO8601 format :

```
var date=DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o")
//2019-09-18T14:02:22.2048166Z
```

[HH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#HH_Specifier) is the double digit specifier that returns a 24-hour value (0-23) while `hh` returns the hour between 0 and 12. When `hh` is used the `t` (AM/PM designator) should also be used, otherwise there's no way to say whether the hour is 10 AM or 10 PM.

This return 14:00 etc :

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fffffff")
//2019-09-18 14:07:48.2517651
```

While this returns

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff")
//2019-09-18 02:08:45.1001800
```

Which is a problem - is this AM or PM? Adding `tt` at the end fixes this, but the returned designator would be localized. To ensure a specific designator is used, we need to pass a CultureInfo parameter :

```
DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
//2019-09-18 02:10:39.9194735 PM
```

Putting it all together, to get the date from BigQuery and then format it as a string using AM/PM :

```
var date=(DateTime?)row["created_at"];
var text=string.Format("{0:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt}",date,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The equivalent using string interpolation would be :

```
var text=FormattableString.Invariant($"{date:yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff tt}");
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use this

```
string newDate = date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fffffff");
```

More on Format specifiers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

Comment: This isn't a question about creating strings. The OP is asking how to convert *something* into a DateTime. That something most likely already is a DateTime but the OP's code converts it into strings in different locales before trying to parse it back

Comment: I think we are over engineering here I see the question in the last line , How can we format this date into a format I want?....And that is what I have tried to answer..

Comment: That's not what was asked. And DateTime has no format. Only strings do

Comment: Again..The Title of the question does not match with what was asked in the description..But let us not argue over it...i rest my case ☺

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how can i get milliseconds?

Comment: @MuhammadHammadEjaz if the value is a DateTime or DateTimeOffset you already have them. If you [check this documentation example](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-dotnet/docs/Google.Cloud.BigQuery.V2/#data-insertion) you'll see that `BigQueryDbType.Timestamp` is mapped to `DateTime`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your help brother. Your solution worked perfectly